# How do I compile a C program which includes Python.h on Windows?

Tags: python, c, gcc

I am trying to learn how to embed a Python interpreter into my C/C++ programs.

I like this concept because it may enable me to extend C programs at run time as well as enable users to write custom scripts/plugins.

Detailed instruction on embedding Python in C is provided at: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

I'm using example code provided in the Python documentation to figure out the mechanics involved:

`embedded.c`

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to compile it on Windows using gcc.

```
C:\Users\user\embedded_python> gcc embedded.c
embedded.c:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I think the problem is I need to link to the Python.h file, but I can't seem to get the compiler flags right:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\embedded_python>gcc -IC:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38 -lPython38 embedded.c
embedded.c:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

How can I get this program to compile on Windows (preferably with gcc/g++ to avoid Visual Studio bloat)?

Comment: Where is your Python.h file located, exactly?

Comment: My Python.h file is in:

`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include`

Comment: Add gcc options `-v -H` to see whether paths are as expected. gcc must be told the folder where that header is located by `-isystem`, but `-I` might also work though.

Comment: Did you try to add `...\include` to your `-I` option?

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, but I suppose if you activate your `Bash` from windows and can perform a work around. First you have to install `python3-dev`

Then use this command line where your file is located, to compile (test is your filename)

```
gcc -Wall test.c -o test  $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python3)
```